# Starting a VNC session on a new X display

Tags: xorg, vnc

I'm currently using `x11vnc` to share my existing X session over VNC.

What I'd like to do is to start a new X session/display which would work and act exactly like the existing one, except wouldn't be visible to someone sitting at my computer. (Problem right now is that people at the office can watch my unattended screen as I work, weird.)

Is there a way that I can do something like this to achieve this:

```
ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 otherhost "x11vnc -newdisplay -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost"
```

to tunnel back the port and connect in a more secure way?

Comment: If the local machine also is running X11, then you don't need to use vnc. There are advantages for just using X11, other advantages for vnc.

Comment: You need one of the other vnc servers, X11vnc ties vnc to an existing X11 display. There are others that do not. Which OS are you running?

Comment: Elementary Luna (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Comment: How is it going. Have you got it working yet, or do you need more help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian 7: install and use `tightvncserver` or `vnc4server`. You probably have similar packages on your system (maybe without the `4`).

type `apt-cache search vnc | grep -v lib | grep server` on any debian based system (including Ubuntu, mint, elementary).

`X11vnc` is the vnc server that connects to an existing X11 server, useful for tech support to help a user etc. But not so good to remote login, without allowing people to see what you are doing.

Also consider using just X11 (no vnc): `ssh -X otherhost`